# Kohana 3 module structure question

Tags: php, kohana, static-methods, kohana-3

everybody! I have a new question about Kohana 3, or rather about a module structure. I develop a small module called Textblock. It's about an ordinary page or a small insertion to the site layout (e.g. a greeting or a slogan, company name). It contains both controllers and models. Models inherit Sprig_MPTT. And one feature I'd like to implement is one could be able to call this module like this:

```
$textblock = Textblock::get_single(1);      //by id
$children  = Textblock::get_children_of(4); //id of parent
```

and not

```
$textblock = Sprig::factory('Textblock')->get_single(1);
$children  = Sprig::factory('Textblock')->get_children_of(4);
```

Those methods are defined in Model_Textblock class as `static`.

So, I made a wrapper class `Textblock`, that inherits `Model_Textblock`. What if I suddenly want change Sprig to Jelly, for example? Foreground won't change at all. Another advantage, imho, is more clarity for anyone, who wants to use this module (e.g. it could be another programmer in the team).

But there's a doubt if I'm on a wrong way... So, the question itself: is the suggested a right way to organize my module? Or it's preferable to keep ordinary `Sprig::factory('Textblock')` where Textblock's functionality is needed, remove additional wrapper class and remove `static`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to extend `Model_Textblock`. You can create a model instance and call its method:

```
class Textblock {
   public static function get_single($id)
   {
      return Sprig::factory('textblock')->get_single($id);
   }
   // etc
}
```

But this way you should copy model methods in your static class (not DRY). Also, what if you have more than one model? All you want (as I understand) is to easily change AR driver. So I'd preffer this kind of class:

```
class Textblock {   

   // saved objects, dont create on model twice
   protected static $_instances = array();

   public static function model($name)
   {
      if (! isset(self::$_instances[$name]))
      {
          $model = Sprig_MPTT::factory($name);
          // you can add try..catch to prevent exceptions
          // or add another checks
          self::$_instances[$name] = $model;
      }
      return clone self::$_instances[$name];
   }
}
```

and use it like `Textblock::model('textblock')->get_single($id)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I want to keep my modules outwardly unchangeable everywhere they are used. And I like the idea when Textblock doesn't inherit Model_Textblock because I think that a module must provide end user with just a limited set of methods that contains the most necessary logic. What do you think about it? And about more than one model: usually I have one model per one entity.